# Applying Black formatter on symlink directory

Tags: python, black-code-formatter

I have the following folder structure:

```
- etl
    - raw
        - raw.py
        - etl (symlink)
            - raw
                - raw.py
                - etl (symlink)
                    ... (infinite paths)
- config.py
```

I've created a [symlink](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-create-symbolic-links-in-linux-using-the-ln-command/) from the `etl` folder. I'm using symlink so that I can have absolute imports from `raw.py` into `config.py`. For example, in `raw.py` I have the following import: `from etl.config import MY_CONSTANT`. This absolute import is made possible due to the symlink.

However, when I try to run Black, as in `poetry run black ${INCLUDE_FILES}` and `INCLUDE_FILES = ./etl` I run into a infinite loop, as Black tryies to enter in the symlinks and keep going forever. This infinite loop doesn't happen with, for example, Pylint and Flake8.

I could try running Black on every single specific `.py` file. However, as I have many files, that'd be time consuming.

Is there a way to make Black ignore the symlinks? Or is there another workaround for my situation?

Comment: How about using one of the options to make absolute imports possible *without* creating infinite loops? Much easier, much more Pythonic, much more portable, etc. etc.

Comment: That'd great. I'm using symlinks just because I can't figure out how to do these absolute imports without them. My current path is `/home/hsmatheus/git/cryptocurrency-monitoring/etl/raw` and my current relative path is `cryptocurrency-monitoring/etl/raw`. These paths have a `-` in them, which is an invalid syntax for Python imports.

Comment: Put empty `__init__.py` files in `etl` and `raw`. This should allow you to use `etl` as a package from the `cryptocurrency-monitoring` directory. Alternatively, you can always use relative imports.

Comment: I ended up renaming my GitHub repo to cryptocurrency_monitor. I removed the symlinks. I also added `__init__.py` files, as it seems to be good practice overall. Then I started using absolute paths as, for example, in `cryptocurrency_monitoring/etl/raw/run.py`: `from cryptocurrency_monitoring.etl.raw.coingecko import run_raw_btc`. Then I run `poetry shell` in `~/git/cryptocurrency_monitoring$`. Then finally I run my code like this: `~/git$ python3 -m cryptocurrency_monitoring.etl.raw.run`. That'll do for now, thanks for the insights @MattDMo

Comment: Glad you got things sorted out. Cheers!